# How to host a nodejs web app?

Tags: express, socket.io

I have a basic chat app created through express and socket.io and I was just running it on a local port for testing. If I would want to have it available as a site, how/where exactly would I go about hosting it. In terms of the code, what would I change the port that my node server listens to? I'm completely new to this so I have little idea how to take this from a local machine to the web.

Comment: Depends on whether you want to pay for it or not. Try [Heroku](https://signup.heroku.com/node?c=70130000001xDpdAAE&gclid=CjwKCAjwzMbLBRBzEiwAfFz4gSmvuif3LMA-O1g6duMiLVGug-6PSfcb6K1OGsehsDd8Aj5UYZ8MjRoC_iMQAvD_BwE) for free hosting under the domain `<domain>.herokuapp.com`. Also, I'm not sure if this is a right question for stackoverflow.

Comment: You find a hosting provider that supports node.js apps and then you following their specific deployment instructions.  To reach it with a domain name, you will also have to acquire and configure a domain name.  Depending upon your hosting provider, you can sometimes do all that through the hosting provider or you go to a DNS provider to get the domain name and then configure it there to point at your hosted server.

Answer (score 2):

You can host your node.js application

- Bluemix
- Heroku
- Amazon Web Services(AWS)
- Microsoft Azure
- AppFog
- RedHat OpenShift
- Xervo
- EngineYard
- Joyent

I will suggest you Heroku or AWS or Microsoft Azure

Well Heroku is free so try Heroku. I have already hosted my chat application there

https://node-chat-app-sourabh.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can try

now.sh 
   Openshift [PaaS] 
   Heroku [PaaS] 
   Linode [IaaS] 
   DigitalOcean [IaaS]

-Basil